# Errors when using cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, torch

I tried to load t7 model with cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch('./models/eccv16/starry_night.t7')
```

But I got an error:

> **cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) ..\modules\dnn\src\torch\THDiskFile.cpp:496: error: (-2:Unspecified
> error) cannot open <./models/eccv16/starry_night.t7> in mode r  in
> function 'TH::THDiskFile_new'**

Any help is appreciated.